# Fetch React Native отправляет пустой POST запрос

Tags: php, javascript-faq

что я делаю не так?, почему POST запрос пустой?, сам запрос до сервера доходит, но почему то пустым

Код клиента

```
function ajaxZapr(mess){
 fetch('https://u2430096.isp.regruhosting.ru/graf.php', {
  
      method: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      body: JSON.stringify(mess)
    });
```

код сервера

```
$phone = !empty($_POST['mess']) ? $_POST['mess'] : 'данные не переданы';
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
$text = $phone;
file_put_contents($filename, $text);
```

Comment: А зачем кодировать `mess` в JSON? Также можно на сервере вывести вообще весь массив `$_POST` и посмотреть что там в нем.

Comment: пустота в нем !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))){
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

вот, с помощью чего я решил данную проблему